# how to use jquery onClick function on element inside a div which were previously appended from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have appended some element inside a div with class `.display_noti` like :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(done,200);
});

function done() {
setTimeout(updates, 200); // Call updates in 200ms
}

function updates(){

  $.getJSON("notification.php",function(data){  
    // you can do checking here
    if ( data.result && data.result.length > 0 ) {
       $(".display_noti").empty(); // Clear out the div  
       $.each(data.result,function(){  
         $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific'>You got a pal request from <strong>"+this['from_user']+"</strong><br><span class='date'>"+this['notification_date']+"<form method='post'><input type='hidden' value='"+this['pals_id']+"'></form></div>");
       }); 
       done();
    }
    else {
          $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific' style='background-color:white;'>You have no notification to view.</div>");
    }
  });
}
```

I have `fetched` data from `database` and converted it on `json encode` format and then I used that above jquery function to get,validate and add those information inside that `div` with class `.display_noti`.

As you guys can see i'm doing this all for my notification system so, every time this code checks new update available or not in my database.If there's some changes in database then in every `200 milliseconds` element inside that `.display_noti` div which mean div with class `.palnotific` will automatically get updated without any page reload/refresh.

Now my problem is that every `200 milliseconds` those `appended` div get vanish and then come again.It's good if there was any new update it will add on my `.display_noti` but it might be not that good if i want to add some jquery `event handler` function like `onclick`.I mean i want to add some `onclick` function on that appended `div`.I want to take that `form` input value and send it via `ajax` to some `php` file for the process and make some changes on database.What will be the proper way to do that in such case?Guys need help.

(In page things doesn't vanish.I was talking about source code where every `200 milliseconds` things appear and vanish repeats)

Comment: is pals_id is auto increment in your db?

Comment: why @VigneswaranS bro?

Comment: i will give a idea. just try it .if your pals_id is auto_increment then we can get the greatest value.it is appended in your div.take that value and have as a variable(var pal).on next update check for var pal<=this[Pals_id].if true append else leave

Comment: have you got it bro?

Comment: bro how can i use jquery `onclick` event?I was hoping to select that form `input` value after when user clicks on any appended div and then catch that value from jquery and use it on ajax to send it on php file for some server way update.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('document').on('click','.palnotific',function(){
    input_val = $(this).find(':input').val();

    //continue ajax here
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.